# Filtering rows on Spark for multiple columns sharing the same value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter

I was trying to search this on stackoverflow, but i couldn't find one. Is there a spark syntax that filters on where two or more columns share the same value? For instance something like

dataFrame.filter($"col01" == $"col02"== $"col03")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is. You got it almost correct put 3 '=' between them

```
dataFrame.filter($"col01" === $"col02"=== $"col03")
```

Example:

```
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Array((1,1,1),(1,2,3))).toDF("col01","col02","col03")

df.filter($"col01" === $"col02"=== $"col03").show(false)
```

Result:

[image: Result]